# Triggering Script VIA URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script calling a lightbox to trigger if the URL is site.com/page.html?globe=1  and it is not working here is the code:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    url = url.toLowerCase();
    if (url.indexOf('globe=1') != -1) {
        $j("a#fancy").fancybox({
            'padding' : 0,
            'overlayShow' : false,
        });
    }
}
});
$j("a#fancy").fancybox({
    'padding' : 0,
    'overlayShow' : false,
});
```

What is wrong and why does it not work?  I have used this before for other scripts other than fancybox and I assume I am typing some code wrong.

Comment: Where is the `fancybox` function you're calling if `globe=1` is present in the URL?

Comment: I added code and tried that did not work.

Comment: `url.indexOf('globe=1')` isn't fail proof. It would also trigger for `?GoogleGlobe=123`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    url = url.toLowerCase();
    if (url.indexOf('globe=1') != -1) {
        $j("a#fancy").fancybox({
            'padding': 0,
            'overlayShow': false // extra comma removed
        });
    }
}); // extra curly bracket removed
$j("a#fancy").fancybox({
    'padding': 0,
    'overlayShow': false // extra comma removed
});
```

There were few errors - a bracket, and 2 commas. Use visual IDE to track the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if(location.search === '?glob=1') { /* YOUR FANCYBOX CODE HERE */}
```

If `glob=1` is the only parameter otherwise use:

```
if(location.search.search('glob=1') !== -1) { /* YOUR FANCYBOX CODE HERE */}
```