# Triggering Script VIA URL variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

As of now, on my page, the following html is working fine to trigger the following javascript function :

```
<a href="javascript:redirectToOtherSection();">Link to other section</a>
```

What I'd like to do is to have the javascript function triggered on page load when a specific variable is added to the URL. (Instead of having it as a link on the page)

For example, if url is www.mysite.com, page loads normally. If URL is www.mysite.com/?variable=1 , the script is triggered and user is redirected.

(I know there are other ways to redirect a user to another page, but I need to use this specific script, since the destination is dynamic from one type of user to another.)

I have very basic javascript knowledge and can't make the code I found here work : [Triggering Script VIA URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900525/triggering-script-via-url) . What they're doing is triggering a fancybox through URL variable. I believe that it's the same thing I want to achieve here. I'm just not to sure how to modify the code to go from "fancybox" to "redirectToOtherSection()"

```
   var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    url = url.toLowerCase();
    if (url.indexOf('globe=1') != -1) {
        $j("a#fancy").fancybox({
            'padding': 0,
            'overlayShow': false // extra comma removed
        });
    }
}); // extra curly bracket removed
$j("a#fancy").fancybox({
    'padding': 0,
    'overlayShow': false // extra comma removed
});
```

They are using jquery, not sure if jquery is needed in my case?
Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Are you referencing jquery in your script before hand? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: _not sure if jquery is needed in my case_. So this is not your code?

Comment: No, I just copy pasted the code from the other solution I found here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900525/triggering-script-via-url

Sorry for the confusion, I too believe I don't need jquery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on what you've said you dont need jquery, try

```
var url = window.location.href;
url = url.toLowerCase();
if (url.indexOf('variable=1') != -1) {  // where variable 1 is wqhats in you url
    redirectToOtherSection();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code. I've tried it and doesn't seem to work. In Chrome developer tool I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: RedirectToOtherSection is not defined " 
But the link on the page using the same script still works fine onclick : <a href="javascript:redirectToOtherSection();">Link to other section</a>

Any idea?
Thanks again

Comment: Placed the code lower in the page (after the actual redirectToOtherSection function) and it works fine!
Thanks

Comment: No worries. Ordering of js is often a pain, just remember that everything is executed from top to bottom so if you call a function that's further down the page, the browser won't yet know about it.